# Sony WH-CH500 Bluetooth headphones don't work in headset mode on Lenovo T480 laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop, headset

I am trying to use a pair of Sony WH-CH500 bluetooth headphones in headset mode with a Lenovo T480 laptop. They work perfectly fine in stereo headphone mode but the moment I enable the headset from the sound settings the audio cuts out completely.

The T480 has a wifi/bt combo Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 chip.

These headphones obviously work with my phone and they work with a different Asus laptop. Perhaps what is really surprising is that I installed a trial version of IVT BlueSoleil software on the T480 and once I paired the headphones using BlueSoleil they work as expected: stereo headphones when listening to music and automatically switch to headset mode when I receive or make a Skype call.

The headphones work, the laptop's hardware is capable (otherwise it wouldn't work in BlueSoleil) so why don't they work without BlueSoleil software (which I can't use once the trial ends)?

I tried installing drivers from lenovo, drivers from intel, purged both and tried using whatever driver windows installed by default and no luck.

Comment: Did you follow the Sony guide exactly for the setup: https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/whch500/v1/en/contents/TP0001613466.html  .  I generally only use Lenovo Drivers on Lenovo Computers.   Try running Lenovo Vantage to see if it can update the drivers with Lenovo drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onboard bluetooth adapters are notoriously bad for audio on Windows without some kind of third party support software. Those headphones are usually quite good on most devices, so ruling out a problem with those. Either pay for the right software or get a dongle that comes with good software.